# how to sum values from all objects within one dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dict:

```
data = {
    'test1': {
        'x1': {
            'z1': 22,
            'z2': 11,
            'z3': 21,
        },
        'x2': {
            'z1': 15,
            'z2': 34,
            'z3': 54,
        }
    },
    'test2': {
        'x1': {
            'z1': 22,
            'z2': 11,
            'z3': 21,
        },
        'x2': {
            'z1': 15,
            'z2': 34,
            'z3': 54,
        }
    }
}
```

And what I would like to do is to sum all z2 objects within 'test1' and ,in this case, get 45

I know that I can do this by:

```
data['test1']['x1']['z2'] + data['test1']['x2']['z2']
```

but would like to know if there is a chance to take it in one code, for example

**`data['test1'][ * ]['z2']`** where the star would represent all objects ( like in excel - this example doesn't work  of course

Wondering if there is a better solution for this problem

Will be thankful for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum`:

```
d = {'test1': {'x1': {'z1': 22, 'z2': 11, 'z3': 21}, 'x2': {'z1': 15, 'z2': 34, 'z3': 54}}, 'test2': {'x1': {'z1': 22, 'z2': 11, 'z3': 21}, 'x2': {'z1': 15, 'z2': 34, 'z3': 54}}}
result = sum(b['z2'] for a, b in d['test1'].items())
```

Output:

```
45
```

Edit: without an explicit loop, you can use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
new_result = reduce(lambda x, y:x+y['z2'], d['test1'].values(), 0)
```

Output:

```
45
```

Comment: Or just iterate `d['test1'].values()` ?

Comment: This is the option, but is there a way to do this without a loop ?

Comment: @akaribi how do you imagine repeating an operation over multiple items *without* a loop would work? What exactly about this answer isn't suitable for you?

Comment: @Ajax1234 if you're going to the point of importing `functools` and using `reduce` with a `lambda`... to avoid the use of a `for` keyword then `sum(map(lambda L: L['z2'], d['test1'].values()))` 
` is still yucky at least it's a bit easier to grok than `reduce` (and no imports required)

Answer (score 0):

I think, Python's `pandas` library would be a great to easily tackle this kind of problems.

Please have a look at the below code.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> data = {
...     'test1': {
...         'x1': {
...             'z1': 22,
...             'z2': 11,
...             'z3': 21,
...         },
...         'x2': {
...             'z1': 15,
...             'z2': 34,
...             'z3': 54,
...         }
...     },
...     'test2': {
...         'x1': {
...             'z1': 22,
...             'z2': 11,
...             'z3': 21,
...         },
...         'x2': {
...             'z1': 15,
...             'z2': 34,
...             'z3': 54,
...         }
...     }
... }
>>>
>>> d = data["test1"]
>>> d
{'x1': {'z1': 22, 'z2': 11, 'z3': 21}, 'x2': {'z1': 15, 'z2': 34, 'z3': 54}}
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()), index=list(d.keys()))
>>> df
    z1  z2  z3
x1  22  11  21
x2  15  34  54
>>>
>>> df.z2.sum()    # 1st way
45
>>>
>>> df["z2"].sum() # 2nd way
45
>>>
```

References »

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html